# 'No Persistence provider for EntityManager' in Play 2.9.x

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am migrating a simple app from Play 2.8.x to Play 2.9.0-RC3. I have followed all of the migration steps listed [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.9.x/Migration29), but I still get an error:

```
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$start$0(DefaultJPAApi.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.start(DefaultJPAApi.java:70)
```

I am using Java 17 and PostgreSQL. My `conf/META/persistence.xml` is:

```
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">

  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml`, the line:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

should become:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

This will resolve the error. The working project is [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_play_framework/tree/main/v_2_9_0/egg_rest_postgres).